# Setting protected attributes with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, factory-bot, attr-protected

FactoryGirl won't set my protected attribute `user.confirmed`. What's the best practice here?

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.name "Tim"          # attr_accessible -- this works
  f.confirmed true      # attr_protected -- doesn't work
end
```

I can do a `@user.confirmed = true` after using my factory, but that's a lot of repetition across a lot of tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using an `after_create` hook works:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.name "Tim"
  f.after_create do |user|
    user.confirmed = true
    user.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Great find. More recent of versions of factory girl changed the syntax to `after(:create)`. See [getting started guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

Answer (score 3):

You would have to pass it into the hash when you create the user since FactoryGirl is protecting it from mass-assignment.

```
user ||= Factory(:user, :confirmed => true)
```

Comment: Works for me on FactoryGirl 2.1.0.

Comment: I'm using 2.3.2, so that could be it but it seems unlikely

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use Rails' built in roles like this:

```
#user.rb
attr_accessor :confirmed, :as => :factory_girl
```

When mass-assigning FactoryGirl broadcasts this role, making this pattern possible.

**Pros:** Keeps factories fast, simple, and clean (less code in callbacks)
**Cons:** You are changing your model code for your tests :(

Some untested suggestions to address the Con:

- You could re-open the class just above your factory.
- You could re-open the class in a [test|spec]_helper